# How to customize QTableView's columns which differ from model

Tags: qt, pyside6

I use a model with a signature like this:

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt, QModelIndex

class PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    """A model to interface a Qt view with pandas dataframe """

    def __init__(self, dataframe: pd.DataFrame, parent=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._dataframe = dataframe
```

And (for clearness) I will store file paths in my dataframe. Let's call it Table1

| index | filename |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 01.jpg |

But I want my table view to provide some read-only columns like file's abspath and size.Let's call it Table2

| index | filename | abs path | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01.jpg | D:/01.jpg | 100KB |

And I don't want to store extra info in Table2 in my disk, only data in Table1 is useful.

Can I custom the QTableView to do this? Or I will have to create 2 models?

Comment: You could create the PandasModel with all the columns, and then hide the "extra" ones in the first table view.

Comment: @musicamante Yes. It's a candidate. The problem is that 1. whenever I edit the file path, I need to update the remaining read-only property, and 2.  the extra info actually contains images, so storing them all is not a good choice.

Comment: I am thinking of a temp table which is like SQL views, but it need to connect with file system so I cannot use a raw Sql View

Comment: You don't have to store anything, and updating the extra info shouldn't be a problem anyway. If you want, you can use two "sources" for the same model, one for the pandas data, and another for the extra info, then override `data` accordingly, by accessing one data list depending on the column.